# removing a character from beginning or end of a string in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have a string that for example can have `-` any where including some white spaces.
I want using regex in Python to remove `-` only if it is before all other non-whitespace chacacters or after all non-white space characters. Also want to remove all whitespaces at the beginning or the end. 
For example:

```
string = '  -  test '
```

it should return

```
string = 'test'
```

or:

```
string = '  -this - '
```

it should return

```
string = 'this'
```

or:

```
string = '  -this-is-nice - '
```

it should return

```
string = 'this-is-nice'
```

Comment: I don't know the Python syntax, but one RE might be `^\s*-?\s*(.*?)\s*-?\s*$`

Comment: How about `​ - test` or `- test`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re
out = re.sub(r'^\s*(-\s*)?|(\s*-)?\s*$', '', input)
```

This will remove at most one instance of `-` at the beginning of the string and at most one instance of `-` at the end of the string. For example, given input `-  - text  - -` , the output will be `- text  -`.

Note that `\s` matches Unicode whitespaces (in Python 3). You will need `re.ASCII` flag to revert it to matching only `[ \t\n\r\f\v]`.

Since you are not very clear about cases such as    `-text`, `-text-`, `-text   -`, the regex above will just output `text` for those 3 cases.

For strings such as   `text`  , the regex will just strip the spaces.

Answer (score 12):

You don't need regex for this. [`str.strip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) strip removes all combinations of characters passed to it, so pass `' -'` or `'- '` to it.

```
>>> s = '  -  test '
>>> s.strip('- ')
'test'
>>> s = '  -this - '
>>> s.strip('- ')
'this'
>>> s =  '  -this-is-nice - '
>>> s.strip('- ')
'this-is-nice'
```

To remove any type of white-space character and `'-'` use `string.whitespace + '-'`.

```
>>> from string import whitespace
>>> s =  '\t\r\n  -this-is-nice - \n'
>>> s.strip(whitespace+'-')
'this-is-nice'
```

Comment: This is a very nice method, however the second answer does everything in one shot, so I up voted this and accepted that one, thanks again for this great solution.

Comment: Second solution is amazing. Fixed my problem. Thank you. +1 vote from me.